# pandas dataframe - string indices must be integers-

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following JSON-File

```
    {"Global Quote": {"01. symbol": "MSFT", "02. open": "194.0000", "03. high": "196.4900", "04. low": 
    "194.0000", "05. price": "196.3200", "06. volume": "22966814", "07. latest trading day": "2020-06- 
     18", "08. previous close": "194.2400", "09. change": "2.0800", "10. change percent": "1.0708%"}}
```

My dict has another dict, which is why I do the following:

```
f = open('data.json',)
meta = json.load(f)
data = meta['Global Quote']
```

Results in the following:

```
{"01. symbol": "MSFT", "02. open": "194.0000", "03. high": "196.4900", "04. low": "194.0000", "05. price": "196.3200", "06. volume": "22966814", "07. latest trading day": "2020-06-18", "08. previous close": "194.2400", "09. change": "2.0800", "10. change percent": "1.0708%"}
```

A direct conversion into a CSV is unfortunately not possible, because the following error is displayed:

```
df = pd.read_json('data.json')
df.to_csv('datatest.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

But if I try to manipulate it via dataframes, I get the following error:

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

info = response.json()

with open('data.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(info, fp)


f = open('data.json',)

meta = json.load(f)
data = meta['Global Quote']

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['symbol','open','high','low','price','volume','latest trading day','previous close','change','change percent'])
for d,p in data.items():
    data_row = [float(p['1. symbol']),float(p['2. open']),float(p['3. high']),float(p['4. low']),float(p['5. price']),int(p['6. volume']),float(p['7. latest trading day']),int(p['8. previous close']),float(p['9. change']),int(p['10. change percent'])]
df =df.sort_values('symbol')

print(df)
df.to_csv('testfile.csv')
```

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Is there a better way to write the file in a CSV? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Aside: why do you write your structure to a JSON file, then read it back into Python from that JSON file in the next lines. What's the use of that?

Comment: It's unclear what you want: the inner dict of your example JSON at the top of your question would result in only one row in your Pandas dataframe. It is, in fact, simply a dict. I'm not even sure if that should be written to a CSV, since the CSV would also only have one row. But if you want a CSV file, just write the dict directly to CSV.

Comment: When I write the dict directly into a CSV, the formatting is not ok. 

My CSV should look exactly like this:
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo&datatype=csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to iterate over all the data items.

Try just passing an index while you are creating your dataframe:

```
f = open('data.json',)

meta = json.load(f)
data = meta['Global Quote']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])
df.to_csv('testfile.csv', index = False)
```

If you have more than one value on the JSON, for instance:

```
{"Global Quote": [{"01. symbol": "MSFT", "02. open": "194.0000", "03. high": "196.4900", "04. low": "194.0000", "05. price": "196.3200", "06. volume": "22966814", "07. latest trading day": "2020-06-18", "08. previous close": "194.2400", "09. change": "2.0800", "10. change percent": "1.0708%"},
                  {"01. symbol": "IBM", "02. open": "228.0000", "03. high": "196.4900", "04. low": "194.0000", "05. price": "196.3200", "06. volume": "22966814", "07. latest trading day": "2020-06-28", "08. previous close": "194.2400", "09. change": "2.0800", "10. change percent": "1.0708%"}]}
```

You can do it like this:

```
import json
f = open('data.json',)

meta = json.load(f)
data = meta['Global Quote']

newdf = pd.DataFrame()
for d in data:
    df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0])
    newdf = newdf.append(df)
newdf.to_csv('testfile.csv', index = False)
```

The outputed csv will look as:

```
01. symbol,02. open,03. high,04. low,05. price,06. volume,07. latest trading day,08. previous close,09. change,10. change percent
MSFT,194.0000,196.4900,194.0000,196.3200,22966814,2020-06-18,194.2400,2.0800,1.0708%
IBM,228.0000,196.4900,194.0000,196.3200,22966814,2020-06-28,194.2400,2.0800,1.0708%
```